# What size is my bathtub?

Tags: bathroom, shower, bathtub, plumbing-fixture

I'm trying to determine the size of my bathtub. My current tub measures 58-3/4" L x 39-3/4" W. Tub has a tile surround. Length is measured between two tiled walls. Width is measured from tiled wall to edge of tub.

I assumed I'd be looking for a 60" L x 40" W alcove tub, however, I cannot readily find this nominal size. What nominal size bathtub should I be searching for?

[image: 39-3/4" Width]

[image: 39-3/4" Width, overall]

[image: 58-3/4" Length]

Answer (score 1):

You are measuring correctly, and 60x40 is rare but they do exist - here's [one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/KOHLER-Proflex-60-in-x-40-in-Oval-Soaking-Bathtub-with-Reversible-Drain-in-White-K-1147-0/100079859).  Much more common are 60x36 and 60x42.

Comment: OK, but that on you've linked is different—it's a drop-in tub.  The OP appears to have/need an alcove tub.  Looks more to me like that's actually a 42" wide tub—most tubs are going to be more or less symmetrical, but the OP's appears to have more width on the apron side, which leads me to believe there's extra wall+tile thickness on the wall side (why, IDK).

Comment: @Huesmann - Good catch.  Re: width - Saw that difference too, wondered if the tile was laid on top of old wall above a 42" tub.  If so, a 42" might slip in under it - if you can get the old one out without wrecking the tile.  Then again, some tubs have the wall side narrower.

Comment: Also, it's not clear if that's a one-piece or two-piece tub.  Pics are poor quality, but it *kinda* looks to me like there may be a separate apron piece.  I don't know that I'd be sanguine about simply slipping a new tub underneath—there's tile in front of the tub.  I suppose you could remove all the tile from the course immediately above the deck and below, but I mean, at that point why not just make life easier on yourself and re-tile completely.